# Where is the DisplayPort is this on my Dell U2312HM monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, displayport

I'm looking for the DisplayPort on my Dell UltraSharp U2312HM monitor so I can connect it to my laptop, but I can't find the DisplayPort on the Dell monitor. The [technical specs page](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u2312h/pd) on the Dell site says the monitor has a DisplayPort, but I don't see it. Am I going blind?

[Various ports seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCYtl.jpg) -- [Various ports with symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roJGW.jpg)

I also find it passing strange that this picture [image: this picture] of the underside of the monitor from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005LN1JEC) doesn't match what I'm seeing on my end, but maybe that's a newer model?

EDIT: Check out the answer below. Turns out I have a Dell P2312H monitor instead of a U2312HM model. Don't make my mistake, folks: make sure you read the model number. In my defense, I picked it up at a garage sale. Surely one of Aesop's fables addresses this particular foible...

Comment: But then why does Dell list DisplayPort under 'Connectivity' on their technical specs page? Surely that would imply that a DisplayPort cable should connect to the external monitor sans adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where is the DisplayPort is this on my Dell U2312HM monitor?**

Okay, so based on your screen shot [Various ports with symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roJGW.jpg), it appears that you are looking at a [Dell Professional P2312H](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2312h/pd) and not the **Dell UltraSharp U2312HM** so you're not going blind.

[image]

Based on [the specs for the **Dell Professional P2312H**](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2312h/pd) it does not have the DisplayPort built into the monitor as the **Dell UltraSharp U2312HM** does.

---

### Further Resources

> [**Dell Professional P2312H**](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2312h/pd)
>
> **Connectivity**
>
> - 1 Digital Visual Interface connectors (DVI-D) with HDCP
> - 1 Video Graphics Array (VGA)
> - 1 USB 2.0 upstream port
> - 2 USB 2.0 downstream ports DC power connector for Dell Soundbar
>
> **STAND**
>
> Height-adjustable stand, tilt , swivel and built in cable-management
> and built-in cable management.
>
> **BUILT-IN DEVICES**
>
> USB 2.0 Hi-Speed Hub (with 1 USB upstream port and 2 USB downstream
> ports)Audio DC-out

Comment: Hot dang! I googled '0GFXN4' which led me to believe I had a U2312HM, and totally missed the model number as you pointed out. Thanks for helping me out!